# Using namespaces in Laravel 4

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and using PHP namespaces in general. I didn't run into any problems until I decided to make a model named File. How would I go about namespacing correctly so I can use my File model class?

The files are `app/controllers/FilesController.php` and `app/models/File.php`. I am trying to make a new `File` in `FilesController.php`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Namespacing is pretty easy once you get that hang of it.

Take the following example:

*app/models/File.php*
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

class File {

    public function someMethodThatGetsFiles()
    {
    
    }
}
```

*app/controllers/FileController.php*
<?php

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\File;

class FileController {

    public function someMethod()
    {
    
        $file = new File();
    }
}
```

**Declare the Namespace:**

```
namespace App\Controllers;
```

Remember, once you've put a class in a Namespace to access any of PHP's built in classes you need to call them from the Root Namespace. e.g: `$stdClass = new stdClass();` will become `$stdClass = new \stdClass();` (see the `\`)

**"Import" other Namespaces:**

```
use App\Models\File;
```

This Allows you to then use the `File` class without the Namespace prefix.

Alternatively you can just call:

```
$file = new App\Models\File();
```

But it's best practice to put it at the top in a `use` statement as you can then see all the file's dependencies without having to scan the code.

Once that's done you need to them run `composer dump-autoload` to update Composer's autoload function to take into account your newly added Classes.

Remember, if you want to access the FileController via a URL then you'll need to define a route and specify the full namespace like so:

```
Route::get('file', 'App\\Controllers\\FileController@someMethod');
```

Which will direct all GET /file requests to the controller's `someMethod()`

Take a look at the PHP documentation on [Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and Nettut's is always a good resource with [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/namespacing-in-php-2/) article

Comment: @JoshHollowway if having FileController extend BaseController this would fail with error of BaseController not found, how do you get around this?

Comment: You'll need to reference BaseController from the root namespace with a \ like this: \BaseController

Comment: i follow the above procedure, but in the end i get the error:
Class 'App\Controllers\BaseController' not found .
after making \BaseController i get the error:
 Class FileController does not exist .
i also do composer dump-autoload

Comment: @JoshHolloway Any chance for an example that uses extends?

Comment: @Zehelvion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374347/phpcs-class-must-be-in-a-namespace-of-at-least-one-level-how-to-fix/27855553#27855553

Comment: @JoshHolloway - but now the problem I see of lot code repetition. In every controller I need to call use App\Models\X.php to use it. Any smarter way to avoid this?

Comment: What actually is namespace use for?

Answer (score 4):

first, load your class with:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

then

```
$file = new File;

// your stuff like:
$file->name = 'thename';
$file->active = true;

$file->save();
```

[Section: Insert, Update, Delete on Laravel 4 Eloquent's doc](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Answer (score 2):

To namespace your model, at the top of your model class right after the opening

Then when you call from controllers you will call new Whatever\Model;

You probably have to do a dump-autoload with composer the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

have a look to it.. hopefully will clear your query....

```
<?php

 namespace app\controllers;
 use yii\web\Controller;
 use app\models\users;
  class UserController extends Controller{
 public function actionIndex()
 {
echo "working on .....";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are defined at the top of PHP classes right after the opening php script tag like this:

```
 <?php
   namespace MyNameSpace;
```

When you then want to use the namespaced class in some other class, you define it like this:

```
new MyNameSpace\PhpClass;
```

or import it at the top of the file (after namespaces if present) like this:

```
 <?php

   //namespace

   use MyNameSpace\MyPHPClass;

   //then later on the code you can instantiate the class normally
   $myphpclass = new MyPHPClass();
```

In Laravel namespaces can be defined anywhere composer can autoload them, I'd recommend defining namespaces within the app directory. So you can define a namespace like Utils for holding Utility classes by creating a Utils directory  in the app directory, creating our utility classes and defining the namespace as we did above.

Afterwards you have run the command to ask composer to autoload classes:

```
 $ composer dump-autoload
```