# How to register a namespace in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The problem:
class PostRepostioryInterface not found for line 4 in PostController.php
or in tinkering with the namespace I've even got class
App\Models\Interfaces\PostRepositoryInterface not found

The questions: How to register a namespace in laravel 4? What do I need to do to get L4 to recognise the classes/interfaces at this namespace?

Larave 3 had a $namespaces static object in ClassLoader where you could add namespaces by

```php
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
  'App\Models\Interfaces' => path('app').'models/interfaces',
));
```

I'm not sure if I have that right for laravel 3 but either way, AutoLoader doesn't exist in Laravel 4 and ClassLoader exists but the method namespaces doesn't exist in ClassLoader in Laravel 4.

I've looked at this but it doesn't seem to work without registering the namespace somehow.
[Using namespaces in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714848/using-namespaces-in-laravel-4)

Example structure:

```
app/models/interfaces
    PostRepostitoryInterface.php
app/models/repositories
    EloquentPostRepository.php


namespaces:
    App\Models\Repositories;
    App\Models\Interfaces;
```

the files:

PostRepositoryInterface.php

```php
<?php namespace App\Models\Interfaces;
interface PostRepositoryInterface {
    public function all();
    public function find($id);
    public function store($data);
}
```

EloquentPostRepository.php

```php
<?php namespace App\Models\Repositories;
use App\Models\Interfaces\PostRepositoryInterface;
class EloquentPostRepository implements PostRepositoryInterface {

    public function all()
    {
        return Post::all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return Post::find($id);
    }

    public function store($data)
    {
        return Post::save($data);
    }
}
```

PostController.php

```php
<?php
use App\Models\Interfaces\PostRepositoryInterface;
class PostsController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct( PostRepositoryInterface $posts )
    {
        $this->posts = $posts; 
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the laravel irc channel I found out the namespaces should work in L4 without a need for registering them anywhere. This is because the composer dump-autoload adds them to the composer/autoload file for me. So that was not an issue.

The issue turned out to be a typo apparently(I can't find it in the code above but after going through every line copy/pasting the class names and namespaces something changed), and also somehow in my real code I left out the 'use' statement for EloquentPostRepository.php

```
use App\Models\Interfaces\PostRepositoryInterface;
```

Now I've hit another wall trying to use the namespaced interface with ioc and the controller constructor (target interface App\Models\Interfaces\PostRepositoryInterface is not instantiable) but I guess that should be a different question.

Comment: Here is the other question if anyone wants to take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236878/laravel-4-target-interface-is-not-instantiable

Answer (score 7):

You probably forgot to do `composer dump-autoload`. This updates the list of classes Laravel autoloads.

You can read more on [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload).

Comment: nope that would be my guess but it wasn't the case. I found a typo and a missing use statement and got the answer to whether it needs registering on the laravel irc. Thanks though :-)