# Laravel 4: Target Interface is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, ioc-container

I've been comparing my code [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236878/laravel-4-target-interface-is-not-instantiable) and many other guides online but with little success. Everything works fine until I try to inject the the interface in my controller. When I do inject it, I get the Target Interface is not instantiable error.

**app\models\Interfaces\InterviewInterface.php**

```
<?php namespace app\models\Interfaces;

interface InterviewInterface {
    public function fetch($id);
}
```

**app\models\Interview.php**

```
use app\models\Interfaces\InterviewInterface;

class Interview extends Eloquent implements InterviewInterface  {

    public function fetch($id)
    {
        return Interview::find($id);
    }

}
```

**routes.php**

```
App::bind('app\models\Interfaces\InterviewInterface');
```

**composer.json**

```
"psr-4": {
        "Blog\\Articles\\" : "app/lib/Blog/Articles",
        "app\\models\\Interfaces\\" : "app/models/Interfaces/InterviewInterface.php"
    }
```

**AdminInterviewController.php**

```
use app\models\Interfaces\InterviewInterface as InterviewInterface;

class AdminInterviewController extends BaseController  {

    public function __construct(InterviewInterface $interview)
    {
         $this->interview = $interview;
         $this->beforeFilter('auth');
    }

}
```

As soon as I add the

```
use app\models\Interfaces\InterviewInterface as InterviewInterface;
```

and

```
__construct(InterviewInterface $interview)
$this->interview = $interview;
```

lines, it gives me the error. I pull them out, no error.

I have run php composer.phar dump-autoload and php artisan dump-autoload commands multiple times and they succeed.

Any ideas? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the interface to a class in order to resolve it from the IOC:

In routes.php, assuming it is not namespaced:

```
App::bind('app\modesl\Interfaces\InterviewInterface', 'Interview');
```

Comment: This whole time I was looking at the other SO question thinking that second argument was for something else. What in the world was I thinking? Many thanks, @Laravelian.
Should App::bind really stay in my routes.php?

Comment: @christf you can use service provider if you want to avoid placing App::bind in your routes.php