# Laravel Package Class

Tags: laravel-4

I am developing my own package in Laravel and I am developing a huge number of helper to use with my package so that it can be used this way:

```
MyPackage::myfunc1();
MyPackage::myfunc2();
MyPackage::myfunc3();
....
```

The problem is MyPackage class (MyPackage.php) is becoming huge and the code is becoming very long. This bring hard maintainability to the file.

Is there anyway that I can split the class into a few files for easier maintaining? Or, is there any other way to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: use namespacing and split helper functions into seperate classes

Comment: @Luceos Thanks for your comment. But it would be nice if you can show me an example for easier understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request:
File: MyPackage/Helpers/FooUtil.php

```
<?PHP
namespace MyPackage\Helpers;

class FooUtil
{

}
```

File: MyPackage/Helpers/BarUtil.php

```
<?PHP
namespace MyPackage\Helpers;

class BarUtil
{

}
```

Example how to use namespaces to seperate classes and how to use different classes in the same namespace. For more information read:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php
- [Using namespaces in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714848/using-namespaces-in-laravel-4)

I generally advice you to read about PSR-0, which is used in Symfony/Laravel to properly support autoloading, composer and packagist: http://petermoulding.com/php/psr
PSR in fact defines how to format namespaces in order to be applicable more globally.

In your example a proper namespacing might be:

`Author\MyPackage\Helper\FooClass`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but how can I get my package facade to link to the new class file? I tried by adding `$loader->alias('MyPackage', 'Vendor\MyPackage\AnotherClass');`, but it seems replacing the existing one instead adding.

Comment: what existing package are you replacing? You probably named your package the same as the one you're replacing. Also better to configure aliases in the config directory under config/app.php