# Laravel integration with Intervention and namespaces?

Tags: php, class, methods, laravel, namespaces

tl;dr - I already did `composer sump-autoload`

Question: 
I am using Intervention Image library.
I am updating an existing app that has an Image class that represents an image model.
I wish to use the Intervention Image Image class by it's full namespace name.

[See example here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714848/using-namespaces-in-laravel-4)

I narrowed down the fault I wish to resolve to an empty test project with a single route:

```
Route::get('/{sugar}.jpg', function($sugar)
{
    $path = 'C:/some-path/';
    $img = Intervention\Image\Image::make($path . $sugar . '.jpg');
    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

This is the problematic line:

```
$img = Intervention\Image\Image::make($path . $sugar . '.jpg');
```

It results in:

```
Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\Image::make()
```

However, the namespace appears to be correct:

https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php

And if I remove the namespace and do:

```
$img = Image::make($path . $sugar . '.jpg');
```

It works perfectly! Only that this would collide with the existing Image class in the real app.

Thanks for reading this far. Any suggestions on how to debug this namespace issue?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the class name is incorrect!
There appears to be a class named image but it's not the one I need.
The correct class name is `ImageManagerStatic`.

You can do this to handle the name collision:

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as someUniqueName;
```

You can also simply change the line in your `config/app` from this

```
        'Image'      => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image',
```

to this

```
        'someUniqueName'      => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image',
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;` to the top of your controller class.

This helped for me getting access to the image controller.

It should or could like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;


class AdminController extends Controller{
```