# phpcs - class must be in a namespace of at least one level - how to fix?

Tags: php, laravel-4, namespaces, phpcodesniffer, laravel-4.2

I am using laravel 4.2.

Lets say there is such class:

```
class BShopsController extends ShopsController
```

To fix this, I try to use name space lets say this:

```
namespace app\controllers;
```

and then it does not find ShopsController

so I add

```
use \ShopsController;
```

Then I get error:

Class BShopsController does not exist

What namespace should I use first of all so it would not break anything?

**Edit:**

BShopsController and ShopsController are in folder Shops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with the help of Shhetri and this [Using namespaces in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714848/using-namespaces-in-laravel-4)

I did this way:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Shops;

class BShopsController extends ShopsController{}
```

Also in routes.php then need to change to this:

```
Route::controller('shops', 'App\Controllers\Shops\ShopsController');
```

And where calling action() method - also need to use namespace.

Also needed to run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

otherwise were errors.

Also in ShopsContrller needed to to this:

```
use \App\Controllers\BaseController;
```

Because Shops controller was in another namespace than BaseController and cannot find it. But is extending from BaseController, so need it.

Answer (score 5):

As your files are inside the Shops folder and I believe that the Shops folder is inside the app folder you should namespace your class the following way.

```
<?php namespace Shops;

class BShopsController extends ShopsController{}
```

Similarly,

```
<?php namespace Shops;

    class ShopsController{}
```

Comment: Shops folder is in controllers folder. Did not mention this because files were controllers, so I assumed you will know already. So now how that change this? Namespace should be controllers/Shops ? Why not app/controllers/Shops for example?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mixed the controllers with the repository thing. Anyways, the solution is still the same. Use the namespace of Shops for the files inside the Shops folder.

Comment: @Darius.V though the solution works I know that I am not being much of a help here. Take a look at this, [namespaces](http://daylerees.com/codebright/the-primers). You will be clear about the namespaces.

Comment: that worked. But then I came to file which is in controllers folder. Using namespace just a backslash is not possible. And then found another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714848/using-namespaces-in-laravel-4 - which suggests namespacing starting from App folder namespace App\Models;
So I guess this should be better?

Comment: yeah...you can start with App. while namespacing a file, use the folder structure convention. It will be easy to give the namespace.