# how to call a class function of an included php file Laravel 4

Tags: object, laravel-4, plivo

I have a php file `plivo.php` in `app/plivo` folder. This included in my controller like,

```
require app_path().'/plivo/plivo.php';
```

The [plivo.php](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-php/blob/master/plivo.php) contains a class, `RestAPI` .

When I try to create an object like,

```
        $auth_id = "Your AUTH_ID";
        $auth_token = "Your AUTH_TOKEN";

        $p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
```

Produce an error:

`Class 'Controllers\Account\RestAPI' not found`

How can I create this object ?

Comment: Try namespacing http://stackoverflow.com/a/14739686/1077125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your class is not namespaced - try and call it like this:

```
    $auth_id = "Your AUTH_ID";
    $auth_token = "Your AUTH_TOKEN";

    $p = new \RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
```

Notice the `\` before `RestAPI`

Comment: How can I call a function?